# Конкатенация двумерных массивов

Tags: java, массивы

ДВС, помогите найти ошибку. Конкатенация двумерных массивов. Массивы подставляются в concatArray, результат выводится в TextView. Компилируется без ошибок, однако при выполнении кода приложение вылетает.

```
public String[][] zap1() {
    String[][] m = new String[5][5];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++)
            if (i == j) m[i][j] = "*";
            else m[i][j] = " ";
    }
    return m;
}

public String[][] zap2() {
    int k, l;
    String[][] m1 = new String[5][5];
    for (k = m1.length - 1; k >= 0; k--)
        for (l = m1[0].length - 1; l >= 0; l--)
            if (l == k) m1[l][k] = "*";
            else m1[l][k] = " ";
    return m1;
}

public String[][] concatArray(String[][] a, String[][] b) {
    if (a == null)
        return b;
    if (b == null)
        return a;
    String[][] r = new String[a.length][a[0].length + b[0].length];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, r, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, r, a[0].length, b[0].length);
    return r;
}
```

Лог выдает, что ошибка в методе конкатенации массивов.

```
Process: com.example.transym, PID: 32084
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=5 srcPos=0 dst.length=5 dstPos=5 length=5
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at com.example.transym.Wmassiv.concatArray(Wmassiv.java:34)
    at com.example.transym.ui.frag2.Frag2Fragment$1.onClick(Frag2Fragment.java:45)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6320)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25087)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:869)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6749)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:845)
```

Comment: Лог выдает, что ошибках из-за попытки обращения к несуществующему элементу массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что arraycopy рассматривает массив как линейный и, в случае двумерного массива, заменяет не элементы в строках как вы хотите, а строки.

Нужен цикл, например такой:

```java
for (i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    System.arraycopy(a[i], 0, r[i], 0, a[i].length);
    System.arraycopy(b[i], 0, r[i], a[i].length, b[i].length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкатенация двумерных массивов построчно:

```java
String[][] a = {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}};
String[][] b = {{"e", "f"}, {"g", "h"}};

String[][] r = IntStream.range(0, a.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> Stream.of(a[i], b[i])
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .toArray(String[]::new))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);

Arrays.stream(r).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [a, b, e, f]
// [c, d, g, h]
```